# Evaluate limit of function

Tags: limits

Evaluate $$\lim _{x\to 0 }\frac{\sin^2x - x^2 \cos^2x}{x^2 \sin^2x}$$
without Taylor expansion.

I know that $$\lim _{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$$

and tried to reduce it to a form like that by rewriting it to

$$\lim _{x\to 0 }\frac{\sin^2x\cdot(1+x^2) - x^2}{x^2 \sin^2x}$$ but it still remains $0/0$.

Comment: Do you mean the Limit $x\to 0$?

Comment: which direction do you mean? $x$ tends to $\infty$ or $x$  tends to zero?

Comment: Have you tried L'Hopital's rule?

Comment: can you use L'Hospital?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I would have to use it $4$ times, isn't there any simpler method?

Comment: The simple method is to use the Taylor series!

Comment: You are on right track. Express it as $1+\dfrac{\sin^{2}x-x^{2}}{x^{2}\sin^{2}x}$ then replace denominator by $x^{4}$. You should now be able to do by one application of L'Hospital's Rule. The answer will come as $1+2(-1/6)=2/3$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Why can I replace the denominator by $x^4$ ?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Advanced methods are not always the simplest.

Comment: Write $\sin^2 x=x^{2}((\sin^2 x) /x^2)$ and second factor goes to $1$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh That should be it. Can post as answer

Comment: Next write $$\frac{\sin^2 x-x^2}{x^4}=\frac{\sin x+x}{x}\cdot\frac{\sin x-x} {x^{3}}$$ first factor tends to $2$ and apply L'Hospital's Rule (only once)  on second to get $-1/6$. Its difficult to type Complete answers via smartphone. Use the material in comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\lim _{x\to 0 }\frac{\sin^2x - x^2 \cos^2x}{x^2 \sin^2x}=\lim _{x\to 0 }\frac{\sin^2x - x^2+x^2 \sin^2x}{x^2 \sin^2x}=\lim _{x\to 0 }\frac{\sin^2x - x^2}{x^2 \sin^2x}+1\\
=\lim _{x\to 0 }\frac{\sin x + x}x\frac{\sin x - x}{x^3}\frac{x^2}{ \sin^2x}+1=2\lim _{x\to 0 }\frac{\sin x - x}{x^3}+1.$$

Then we can apply L'Hospital twice,

$$\frac{\sin x-x}{x^3}\to\frac{\cos x}{3x^2}\to\frac{-\sin x }{6x}\to-\frac16.$$

---

You can avoid L'Hospital with

$$L:=\lim _{x\to 0 }\frac{\sin x - x}{x^3}=\lim _{x\to 0 }\frac{\sin3x - 3x}{(3x)^3}=\lim _{x\to 0 }\frac{3\sin x-4\sin^3x - 3x}{27x^3}\\
=\lim _{x\to 0 }\frac{3(\sin x-x)-4\sin^3x}{27x^3}=\frac L9-\frac4{27}.$$

Answer (score 1):

write your term in the form
$$\frac{\tan(x)^2-x^2}{x^2\tan(x)^2}$$ and use L'Hospital

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{sin^2x -x^2cos^2x}{x^2sin^2x}$

$= \lim_{x\to 0} [\frac{sin^2x}{x^2sin^2x} -\frac{x^2cos^2x}{x^2sin^2x}]$

$=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x^2} - \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{sin^2x} + \lim_{x\to 0} \frac {sin^2x}{sin^2x}(=1)$

Now,  $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x^2} (≡ \frac{1}{0} form) $

and $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{sin^2x} (≡ \frac{1}{0} form) $

So, we are going to use L'Hospital for  two  of    them

We've $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{2x} -  \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{2sinxcosx}$

Again using L'Hosptal,

$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{2} - \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{2cos^2x-2sin^2x}$

$=\frac{1}{2}- \frac{1}{2} = 0$

Therefore, the total value of the limit $= 0 + 1 = 1$

Comment: You can't use L'Hospital's rule if the form is $1/0$. Only for $\infty/\infty$ or $0/0$. $\frac{1}{x^2} \rightarrow +\infty$ as x tends to 0.